# What is your favorite R debugging trick?

Tags: debugging, r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [General suggestions for debugging R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442518/general-suggestions-for-debugging-r)

I've recently started using `browser()` in function definitions for debugging (a great tool!). I feel like `print()` debugging has been slowing my learning curve of built-in debugging tools. What are some others I've been missing?