# Grouping functions (tapply, by, aggregate) and the *apply family

Tags: r, vectorization, apply, r-faq

Whenever I want to do something "map"py in R, I usually try to use a function in the `apply` family.

However, I've never quite understood the differences between them -- how {`sapply`, `lapply`, etc.} apply the function to the input/grouped input, what the output will look like, or even what the input can be -- so I often just go through them all until I get what I want.

Can someone explain how to use which one when?

My current (probably incorrect/incomplete) understanding is...

1. `sapply(vec, f)`: input is a vector. output is a vector/matrix, where element `i` is `f(vec[i])`, giving you a matrix if `f` has a multi-element output
2. `lapply(vec, f)`: same as `sapply`, but output is a list?
3. `apply(matrix, 1/2, f)`: input is a matrix. output is a vector, where element `i` is f(row/col i of the matrix)
4. `tapply(vector, grouping, f)`: output is a matrix/array, where an element in the matrix/array is the value of `f` at a grouping `g` of the vector, and `g` gets pushed to the row/col names
5. `by(dataframe, grouping, f)`: let `g` be a grouping. apply `f` to each column of the group/dataframe. pretty print the grouping and the value of `f` at each column.
6. `aggregate(matrix, grouping, f)`: similar to `by`, but instead of pretty printing the output, aggregate sticks everything into a dataframe.

Side question: I still haven't learned plyr or reshape -- would `plyr` or `reshape` replace all of these entirely?

Comment: to your side question: for many things plyr is a direct replacement for `*apply()` and `by`. plyr (at least to me) seems much more consistent in that I always know exactly what data format it expects and exactly what it will spit out. That saves me a lot of hassle.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend adding: `doBy` and the selection & apply capabilities of `data.table`.

Comment: `sapply` is just `lapply` with the addition of `simplify2array` on the output. `apply` does coerce to atomic vector, but output can be vector or list. `by` splits dataframes into sub-dataframes, but it doesn't use `f` on columns separately. Only if there is a method for 'data.frame'-class might `f` get column-wise applied by `by`.  `aggregate` is generic so different methods exist for different classes of the first argument.

Comment: Mnemonic: l is for 'list', s is for 'simplifying', t is for 'per type' (each level of the grouping is a type)

Comment: There also exist some functions in the package Rfast, like: eachcol.apply, apply.condition, and more, which are faster than R's equivalents

Answer (score 1440, accepted):

R has many *apply functions which are ably described in the help files (e.g. `?apply`). There are enough of them, though, that beginning useRs may have difficulty deciding which one is appropriate for their situation or even remembering them all. They may have a general sense that "I should be using an *apply function here", but it can be tough to keep them all straight at first.

Despite the fact (noted in other answers) that much of the functionality of the *apply family is covered by the extremely popular `plyr` package, the base functions remain useful and worth knowing.

This answer is intended to act as a sort of **signpost** for new useRs to help direct them to the correct *apply function for their particular problem. Note, this is **not** intended to simply regurgitate or replace the R documentation! The hope is that this answer helps you to decide which *apply function suits your situation and then it is up to you to research it further. With one exception, performance differences will not be addressed.

- **apply** - *When you want to apply a function to the rows or columns
  of a matrix (and higher-dimensional analogues); not generally advisable for data frames as it will coerce to a matrix first.*

  ```
   # Two dimensional matrix
   M <- matrix(seq(1,16), 4, 4)

   # apply min to rows
   apply(M, 1, min)
   [1] 1 2 3 4

   # apply max to columns
   apply(M, 2, max)
   [1]  4  8 12 16

   # 3 dimensional array
   M <- array( seq(32), dim = c(4,4,2))

   # Apply sum across each M[*, , ] - i.e Sum across 2nd and 3rd dimension
   apply(M, 1, sum)
   # Result is one-dimensional
   [1] 120 128 136 144

   # Apply sum across each M[*, *, ] - i.e Sum across 3rd dimension
   apply(M, c(1,2), sum)
   # Result is two-dimensional
        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
   [1,]   18   26   34   42
   [2,]   20   28   36   44
   [3,]   22   30   38   46
   [4,]   24   32   40   48
  ```

  If you want row/column means or sums for a 2D matrix, be sure to
  investigate the highly optimized, lightning-quick `colMeans`,
  `rowMeans`, `colSums`, `rowSums`.
- **lapply** - *When you want to apply a function to each element of a
  list in turn and get a list back.*

  This is the workhorse of many of the other *apply functions. Peel
  back their code and you will often find `lapply` underneath.

  ```
   x <- list(a = 1, b = 1:3, c = 10:100) 
   lapply(x, FUN = length) 
   $a 
   [1] 1
   $b 
   [1] 3
   $c 
   [1] 91
   lapply(x, FUN = sum) 
   $a 
   [1] 1
   $b 
   [1] 6
   $c 
   [1] 5005
  ```
- **sapply** - *When you want to apply a function to each element of a
  list in turn, but you want a **vector** back, rather than a list.*

  If you find yourself typing `unlist(lapply(...))`, stop and consider
  `sapply`.

  ```
   x <- list(a = 1, b = 1:3, c = 10:100)
   # Compare with above; a named vector, not a list 
   sapply(x, FUN = length)  
   a  b  c   
   1  3 91

   sapply(x, FUN = sum)   
   a    b    c    
   1    6 5005
  ```

  In more advanced uses of `sapply` it will attempt to coerce the
  result to a multi-dimensional array, if appropriate. For example, if our function returns vectors of the same length, `sapply` will use them as columns of a matrix:

  ```
   sapply(1:5,function(x) rnorm(3,x))
  ```

  If our function returns a 2 dimensional matrix, `sapply` will do essentially the same thing, treating each returned matrix as a single long vector:

  ```
   sapply(1:5,function(x) matrix(x,2,2))
  ```

  Unless we specify `simplify = "array"`, in which case it will use the individual matrices to build a multi-dimensional array:

  ```
   sapply(1:5,function(x) matrix(x,2,2), simplify = "array")
  ```

  Each of these behaviors is of course contingent on our function returning vectors or matrices of the same length or dimension.
- **vapply** - *When you want to use `sapply` but perhaps need to
  squeeze some more speed out of your code or [want more type safety](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339650/why-is-vapply-safer-than-sapply/12340888#12340888).*

  For `vapply`, you basically give R an example of what sort of thing
  your function will return, which can save some time coercing returned
  values to fit in a single atomic vector.

  ```
   x <- list(a = 1, b = 1:3, c = 10:100)
   #Note that since the advantage here is mainly speed, this
   # example is only for illustration. We're telling R that
   # everything returned by length() should be an integer of 
   # length 1. 
   vapply(x, FUN = length, FUN.VALUE = 0L) 
   a  b  c  
   1  3 91
  ```
- **mapply** - *For when you have several data structures (e.g.
  vectors, lists) and you want to apply a function to the 1st elements
  of each, and then the 2nd elements of each, etc., coercing the result
  to a vector/array as in `sapply`.*

  This is multivariate in the sense that your function must accept
  multiple arguments.

  ```
   #Sums the 1st elements, the 2nd elements, etc. 
   mapply(sum, 1:5, 1:5, 1:5) 
   [1]  3  6  9 12 15
   #To do rep(1,4), rep(2,3), etc.
   mapply(rep, 1:4, 4:1)   
   [[1]]
   [1] 1 1 1 1

   [[2]]
   [1] 2 2 2

   [[3]]
   [1] 3 3

   [[4]]
   [1] 4
  ```
- **Map** - *A wrapper to `mapply` with `SIMPLIFY = FALSE`, so it is guaranteed to return a list.*

  ```
   Map(sum, 1:5, 1:5, 1:5)
   [[1]]
   [1] 3

   [[2]]
   [1] 6

   [[3]]
   [1] 9

   [[4]]
   [1] 12

   [[5]]
   [1] 15
  ```
- **rapply** - *For when you want to apply a function to each element of a **nested list** structure, recursively.*

  To give you some idea of how uncommon `rapply` is, I forgot about it when first posting this answer! Obviously, I'm sure many people use it, but YMMV. `rapply` is best illustrated with a user-defined function to apply:

  ```
   # Append ! to string, otherwise increment
   myFun <- function(x){
       if(is.character(x)){
         return(paste(x,"!",sep=""))
       }
       else{
         return(x + 1)
       }
   }

   #A nested list structure
   l <- list(a = list(a1 = "Boo", b1 = 2, c1 = "Eeek"), 
             b = 3, c = "Yikes", 
             d = list(a2 = 1, b2 = list(a3 = "Hey", b3 = 5)))


   # Result is named vector, coerced to character          
   rapply(l, myFun)

   # Result is a nested list like l, with values altered
   rapply(l, myFun, how="replace")
  ```
- **tapply** - *For when you want to apply a function to **subsets** of a
  vector and the subsets are defined by some other vector, usually a
  factor.*

  The black sheep of the *apply family, of sorts. The help file's use of
  the phrase "ragged array" can be a bit [confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297201/explain-r-tapply-description/6297396#6297396), but it is actually
  quite simple.

  A vector:

  ```
   x <- 1:20
  ```

  A factor (of the same length!) defining groups:

  ```
   y <- factor(rep(letters[1:5], each = 4))
  ```

  Add up the values in `x` within each subgroup defined by `y`:

  ```
   tapply(x, y, sum)  
    a  b  c  d  e  
   10 26 42 58 74
  ```

  More complex examples can be handled where the subgroups are defined
  by the unique combinations of a list of several factors. `tapply` is
  similar in spirit to the split-apply-combine functions that are
  common in R (`aggregate`, `by`, `ave`, `ddply`, etc.) Hence its
  black sheep status.

Comment: Believe you will find that `by` is pure split-lapply and `aggregate` is `tapply` at their cores. I think black sheep make excellent fabric.

Comment: Fantastic response! This should be part of the official R documentation :). One tiny suggestion: perhaps add some bullets on using `aggregate` and `by` as well? (I finally understand them after your description!, but they're pretty common, so it might be useful to separate out and have some specific examples for those two functions.)

Comment: Yeah ... what is a ragged array, anyway?

Answer (score 211):

On the side note, here is how the various `plyr` functions correspond to the base `*apply` functions (from the intro to plyr document from the plyr webpage http://had.co.nz/plyr/)

```
Base function   Input   Output   plyr function 
---------------------------------------
aggregate        d       d       ddply + colwise 
apply            a       a/l     aaply / alply 
by               d       l       dlply 
lapply           l       l       llply  
mapply           a       a/l     maply / mlply 
replicate        r       a/l     raply / rlply 
sapply           l       a       laply
```

One of the goals of `plyr` is to provide consistent naming conventions for each of the functions, encoding the input and output data types in the function name. It also provides consistency in output, in that output from `dlply()` is easily passable to `ldply()` to produce useful output, etc.

Conceptually, learning `plyr` is no more difficult than understanding the base `*apply` functions.

`plyr` and `reshape` functions have replaced almost all of these functions in my every day use. But, also from the Intro to Plyr document:

> Related functions `tapply` and `sweep` have no corresponding function in `plyr`, and remain useful. `merge` is useful for combining summaries with the original data.

Comment: When I started learning R from scratch I found plyr MUCH easier to learn than the `*apply()` family of functions. For me, `ddply()` was very intuitive as I was familiar with SQL aggregation functions. `ddply()` became my hammer for solving many problems, some of which could have been better solved with other commands.

Answer (score 148):

From slide 21 of http://www.slideshare.net/hadley/plyr-one-data-analytic-strategy:

[image: apply, sapply, lapply, by, aggregate]

(Hopefully it's clear that `apply` corresponds to @Hadley's `aaply` and `aggregate` corresponds to @Hadley's `ddply` etc. Slide 20 of the same slideshare will clarify if you don't get it from this image.)

(on the left is input, on the top is output)

Answer (score 118):

First start with [Joran's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7141669/181638) -- doubtful anything can better that.

Then the following mnemonics may help to remember the distinctions between each.  Whilst some are obvious, others may be less so --- for these you'll find justification in Joran's discussions.

**Mnemonics**

- `lapply` is a *list* apply which acts on a list or vector and returns a list.
- `sapply` is a *simple* `lapply` (function defaults to returning a vector or matrix when possible)
- `vapply` is a *verified apply* (allows the return object type to be prespecified)
- `rapply` is a *recursive* apply for nested lists, i.e. lists within lists
- `tapply` is a *tagged* apply where the tags identify the subsets
- `apply`  is  *generic*: applies a function to a matrix's rows or columns (or, more generally, to dimensions of an array)

**Building the Right Background**

If using the `apply` family still feels a bit alien to you, then it might be that you're missing a key point of view.

These two articles can help.  They provide the necessary background to motivate the **functional programming techniques** that are being provided by the `apply` family of functions.

Users of Lisp will recognise the paradigm immediately.  If you're not familiar with Lisp, once you get your head around FP, you'll have gained a powerful point of view for use in R -- and `apply` will make a lot more sense.

- [Advanced R: Functional Programming](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html), by Hadley Wickham
- [Simple Functional Programming in R](http://www.bioinformaticszen.com/post/simple-functional-programming-in-r/), by Michael Barton

Answer (score 63):

Since I realized that (the very excellent) answers of this post lack of `by` and `aggregate` explanations. Here is my contribution.

#### BY

The `by` function, as stated in the documentation can be though, as a "wrapper" for `tapply`. The power of `by` arises when we want to compute a task that `tapply` can't handle. One example is this code:

```
ct <- tapply(iris$Sepal.Width , iris$Species , summary )
cb <- by(iris$Sepal.Width , iris$Species , summary )

 cb
iris$Species: setosa
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  2.300   3.200   3.400   3.428   3.675   4.400 
-------------------------------------------------------------- 
iris$Species: versicolor
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  2.000   2.525   2.800   2.770   3.000   3.400 
-------------------------------------------------------------- 
iris$Species: virginica
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  2.200   2.800   3.000   2.974   3.175   3.800 


ct
$setosa
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  2.300   3.200   3.400   3.428   3.675   4.400 

$versicolor
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  2.000   2.525   2.800   2.770   3.000   3.400 

$virginica
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  2.200   2.800   3.000   2.974   3.175   3.800
```

If we print these two objects, `ct` and `cb`, we "essentially" have the same results and the only differences are in how they are shown and the different `class` attributes, respectively `by` for `cb` and `array` for `ct`.

As I've said, the power of `by` arises when we can't use `tapply`; the following code is one example:

```
 tapply(iris, iris$Species, summary )
Error in tapply(iris, iris$Species, summary) : 
  arguments must have same length
```

R says that arguments must have the same lengths, say "we want to calculate the `summary` of all variable in `iris` along the factor `Species`": but R just can't do that because it does not know how to handle.

With the `by` function R dispatch a specific method for `data frame` class and then let the `summary` function works even if the length of the first argument (and the type too) are different.

```
bywork <- by(iris, iris$Species, summary )

bywork
iris$Species: setosa
  Sepal.Length    Sepal.Width     Petal.Length    Petal.Width          Species  
 Min.   :4.300   Min.   :2.300   Min.   :1.000   Min.   :0.100   setosa    :50  
 1st Qu.:4.800   1st Qu.:3.200   1st Qu.:1.400   1st Qu.:0.200   versicolor: 0  
 Median :5.000   Median :3.400   Median :1.500   Median :0.200   virginica : 0  
 Mean   :5.006   Mean   :3.428   Mean   :1.462   Mean   :0.246                  
 3rd Qu.:5.200   3rd Qu.:3.675   3rd Qu.:1.575   3rd Qu.:0.300                  
 Max.   :5.800   Max.   :4.400   Max.   :1.900   Max.   :0.600                  
-------------------------------------------------------------- 
iris$Species: versicolor
  Sepal.Length    Sepal.Width     Petal.Length   Petal.Width          Species  
 Min.   :4.900   Min.   :2.000   Min.   :3.00   Min.   :1.000   setosa    : 0  
 1st Qu.:5.600   1st Qu.:2.525   1st Qu.:4.00   1st Qu.:1.200   versicolor:50  
 Median :5.900   Median :2.800   Median :4.35   Median :1.300   virginica : 0  
 Mean   :5.936   Mean   :2.770   Mean   :4.26   Mean   :1.326                  
 3rd Qu.:6.300   3rd Qu.:3.000   3rd Qu.:4.60   3rd Qu.:1.500                  
 Max.   :7.000   Max.   :3.400   Max.   :5.10   Max.   :1.800                  
-------------------------------------------------------------- 
iris$Species: virginica
  Sepal.Length    Sepal.Width     Petal.Length    Petal.Width          Species  
 Min.   :4.900   Min.   :2.200   Min.   :4.500   Min.   :1.400   setosa    : 0  
 1st Qu.:6.225   1st Qu.:2.800   1st Qu.:5.100   1st Qu.:1.800   versicolor: 0  
 Median :6.500   Median :3.000   Median :5.550   Median :2.000   virginica :50  
 Mean   :6.588   Mean   :2.974   Mean   :5.552   Mean   :2.026                  
 3rd Qu.:6.900   3rd Qu.:3.175   3rd Qu.:5.875   3rd Qu.:2.300                  
 Max.   :7.900   Max.   :3.800   Max.   :6.900   Max.   :2.500
```

it works indeed and the result is very surprising. It is an object of class `by` that along `Species` (say, for each of them) computes the `summary` of each variable.

Note that if the first argument is a `data frame`, the dispatched function must have a method for that class of objects. For example is we use this code with the `mean` function we will have this code that has no sense at all:

```
 by(iris, iris$Species, mean)
iris$Species: setosa
[1] NA
------------------------------------------- 
iris$Species: versicolor
[1] NA
------------------------------------------- 
iris$Species: virginica
[1] NA
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(data[x, , drop = FALSE], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(data[x, , drop = FALSE], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
3: In mean.default(data[x, , drop = FALSE], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

#### AGGREGATE

`aggregate` can be seen as another a different way of use `tapply` if we use it in such a way.

```
at <- tapply(iris$Sepal.Length , iris$Species , mean)
ag <- aggregate(iris$Sepal.Length , list(iris$Species), mean)

 at
    setosa versicolor  virginica 
     5.006      5.936      6.588 
 ag
     Group.1     x
1     setosa 5.006
2 versicolor 5.936
3  virginica 6.588
```

The two immediate differences are that the second argument of `aggregate` **must** be a list while `tapply` **can** (not mandatory) be a list and that the output of `aggregate` is a data frame while the one of `tapply` is an `array`.

The power of `aggregate` is that it can handle easily subsets of the data with `subset` argument and that it has methods for `ts` objects and `formula` as well.

These elements make `aggregate` easier to work with that `tapply` in some situations.
Here are some examples (available in documentation):

```
ag <- aggregate(len ~ ., data = ToothGrowth, mean)

 ag
  supp dose   len
1   OJ  0.5 13.23
2   VC  0.5  7.98
3   OJ  1.0 22.70
4   VC  1.0 16.77
5   OJ  2.0 26.06
6   VC  2.0 26.14
```

We can achieve the same with `tapply` but the syntax is slightly harder and the output (in some circumstances) less readable:

```
att <- tapply(ToothGrowth$len, list(ToothGrowth$dose, ToothGrowth$supp), mean)

 att
       OJ    VC
0.5 13.23  7.98
1   22.70 16.77
2   26.06 26.14
```

There are other times when we can't use `by` or `tapply` and we have to use `aggregate`.

```
 ag1 <- aggregate(cbind(Ozone, Temp) ~ Month, data = airquality, mean)

 ag1
  Month    Ozone     Temp
1     5 23.61538 66.73077
2     6 29.44444 78.22222
3     7 59.11538 83.88462
4     8 59.96154 83.96154
5     9 31.44828 76.89655
```

We cannot obtain the previous result with `tapply` in one call but we have to calculate the mean along `Month` for each elements and then combine them (also note that we have to call the `na.rm = TRUE`, because the `formula` methods of the `aggregate` function has by default the `na.action = na.omit`):

```
ta1 <- tapply(airquality$Ozone, airquality$Month, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
ta2 <- tapply(airquality$Temp, airquality$Month, mean, na.rm = TRUE)

 cbind(ta1, ta2)
       ta1      ta2
5 23.61538 65.54839
6 29.44444 79.10000
7 59.11538 83.90323
8 59.96154 83.96774
9 31.44828 76.90000
```

while with `by` we just can't achieve that in fact the following function call returns an error (but most likely it is related to the supplied function, `mean`):

```
by(airquality[c("Ozone", "Temp")], airquality$Month, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Other times the results are the same and the differences are just in the class (and then how it is shown/printed and not only  -- example, how to subset it) object:

```
byagg <- by(airquality[c("Ozone", "Temp")], airquality$Month, summary)
aggagg <- aggregate(cbind(Ozone, Temp) ~ Month, data = airquality, summary)
```

The previous code achieve the same goal and results, at some points what tool to use is just a matter of personal tastes and needs; the previous two objects have very different needs in terms of subsetting.

Answer (score 40):

There are lots of great answers which discuss differences in the use cases for each function. None of the answer discuss the differences in performance. That is reasonable cause various functions expects various input and produces various output, yet most of them have a general common objective to evaluate by series/groups. My answer is going to focus on performance. Due to above the input creation from the vectors is included in the timing, also the `apply` function is not measured.

I have tested two different functions `sum` and `length` at once. Volume tested is 50M on input and 50K on output. I have also included two currently popular packages which were not widely used at the time when question was asked, `data.table` and `dplyr`. Both are definitely worth to look if you are aiming for good performance.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
n = 5e7
k = 5e5
x = runif(n)
grp = sample(k, n, TRUE)

timing = list()

# sapply
timing[["sapply"]] = system.time({
    lt = split(x, grp)
    r.sapply = sapply(lt, function(x) list(sum(x), length(x)), simplify = FALSE)
})

# lapply
timing[["lapply"]] = system.time({
    lt = split(x, grp)
    r.lapply = lapply(lt, function(x) list(sum(x), length(x)))
})

# tapply
timing[["tapply"]] = system.time(
    r.tapply <- tapply(x, list(grp), function(x) list(sum(x), length(x)))
)

# by
timing[["by"]] = system.time(
    r.by <- by(x, list(grp), function(x) list(sum(x), length(x)), simplify = FALSE)
)

# aggregate
timing[["aggregate"]] = system.time(
    r.aggregate <- aggregate(x, list(grp), function(x) list(sum(x), length(x)), simplify = FALSE)
)

# dplyr
timing[["dplyr"]] = system.time({
    df = data_frame(x, grp)
    r.dplyr = summarise(group_by(df, grp), sum(x), n())
})

# data.table
timing[["data.table"]] = system.time({
    dt = setnames(setDT(list(x, grp)), c("x","grp"))
    r.data.table = dt[, .(sum(x), .N), grp]
})

# all output size match to group count
sapply(list(sapply=r.sapply, lapply=r.lapply, tapply=r.tapply, by=r.by, aggregate=r.aggregate, dplyr=r.dplyr, data.table=r.data.table), 
       function(x) (if(is.data.frame(x)) nrow else length)(x)==k)
#    sapply     lapply     tapply         by  aggregate      dplyr data.table 
#      TRUE       TRUE       TRUE       TRUE       TRUE       TRUE       TRUE
```

```
# print timings
as.data.table(sapply(timing, `[[`, "elapsed"), keep.rownames = TRUE
              )[,.(fun = V1, elapsed = V2)
                ][order(-elapsed)]
#          fun elapsed
#1:  aggregate 109.139
#2:         by  25.738
#3:      dplyr  18.978
#4:     tapply  17.006
#5:     lapply  11.524
#6:     sapply  11.326
#7: data.table   2.686
```

Answer (score 32):

Despite all the great answers here, there are 2 more base functions that deserve to be mentioned, the useful `outer` function and the obscure `eapply` function

**outer**

`outer` is a very useful function hidden as a more mundane one. If you read the help for `outer` its description says:

```
The outer product of the arrays X and Y is the array A with dimension  
c(dim(X), dim(Y)) where element A[c(arrayindex.x, arrayindex.y)] =   
FUN(X[arrayindex.x], Y[arrayindex.y], ...).
```

which makes it seem like this is only useful for linear algebra type things.  However, it can be used much like `mapply` to apply a function to two vectors of inputs. The difference is that `mapply` will apply the function to the first two elements and then the second two etc, whereas `outer` will apply the function to every combination of one element from the first vector and one from the second. For example:

```
 A<-c(1,3,5,7,9)
 B<-c(0,3,6,9,12)

mapply(FUN=pmax, A, B)

> mapply(FUN=pmax, A, B)
[1]  1  3  6  9 12

outer(A,B, pmax)

 > outer(A,B, pmax)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    1    3    6    9   12
 [2,]    3    3    6    9   12
 [3,]    5    5    6    9   12
 [4,]    7    7    7    9   12
 [5,]    9    9    9    9   12
```

I have personally used this when I have a vector of values and a vector of conditions and wish to see which values meet which conditions.

**eapply**

`eapply` is like `lapply` except that rather than applying a function to every element in a list, it applies a function to every element in an environment. For example if you want to find a list of user defined functions in the global environment:

```
A<-c(1,3,5,7,9)
B<-c(0,3,6,9,12)
C<-list(x=1, y=2)
D<-function(x){x+1}

> eapply(.GlobalEnv, is.function)
$A
[1] FALSE

$B
[1] FALSE

$C
[1] FALSE

$D
[1] TRUE
```

Frankly I don't use this very much but if you are building a lot of packages or create a lot of environments it may come in handy.

Answer (score 26):

It is maybe worth mentioning `ave`. `ave` is `tapply`'s friendly cousin. It returns results in a form that you can plug straight back into your data frame.

```
dfr <- data.frame(a=1:20, f=rep(LETTERS[1:5], each=4))
means <- tapply(dfr$a, dfr$f, mean)
##  A    B    C    D    E 
## 2.5  6.5 10.5 14.5 18.5 

## great, but putting it back in the data frame is another line:

dfr$m <- means[dfr$f]

dfr$m2 <- ave(dfr$a, dfr$f, FUN=mean) # NB argument name FUN is needed!
dfr
##   a f    m   m2
##   1 A  2.5  2.5
##   2 A  2.5  2.5
##   3 A  2.5  2.5
##   4 A  2.5  2.5
##   5 B  6.5  6.5
##   6 B  6.5  6.5
##   7 B  6.5  6.5
##   ...
```

There is nothing in the base package that works like `ave` for whole data frames (as `by` is like `tapply` for data frames). But you can fudge it:

```
dfr$foo <- ave(1:nrow(dfr), dfr$f, FUN=function(x) {
    x <- dfr[x,]
    sum(x$m*x$m2)
})
dfr
##     a f    m   m2    foo
## 1   1 A  2.5  2.5    25
## 2   2 A  2.5  2.5    25
## 3   3 A  2.5  2.5    25
## ...
```

Answer (score 14):

I recently discovered the rather useful `sweep` function and add it here for the sake of completeness:

**sweep**

The basic idea is to *sweep* through an array row- or column-wise and return a modified array. An example will make this clear (source: [datacamp](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-tutorial-apply-family#sweep)):

Let's say you have a matrix and want to [standardize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) it column-wise:

```
dataPoints <- matrix(4:15, nrow = 4)

# Find means per column with `apply()`
dataPoints_means <- apply(dataPoints, 2, mean)

# Find standard deviation with `apply()`
dataPoints_sdev <- apply(dataPoints, 2, sd)

# Center the points 
dataPoints_Trans1 <- sweep(dataPoints, 2, dataPoints_means,"-")

# Return the result
dataPoints_Trans1
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,] -1.5 -1.5 -1.5
## [2,] -0.5 -0.5 -0.5
## [3,]  0.5  0.5  0.5
## [4,]  1.5  1.5  1.5

# Normalize
dataPoints_Trans2 <- sweep(dataPoints_Trans1, 2, dataPoints_sdev, "/")

# Return the result
dataPoints_Trans2
##            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
## [1,] -1.1618950 -1.1618950 -1.1618950
## [2,] -0.3872983 -0.3872983 -0.3872983
## [3,]  0.3872983  0.3872983  0.3872983
## [4,]  1.1618950  1.1618950  1.1618950
```

NB: for this simple example the same result can of course be achieved more easily by
 `apply(dataPoints, 2, scale)`

Comment: Is this related to grouping?

Comment: @Frank: Well, to be honest with you the title of this post is rather misleading: when you read the question itself it is about "the apply family". `sweep` is a higher-order function like all the others mentioned here, e.g. `apply`, `sapply`, `lapply` So the same question could be asked about the accepted answer with over 1,000 upvotes and the examples given therein. Just have a look at the example given for `apply` there.

Comment: sweep has a misleading name, misleading defaults, and misleading parameter name :). It's easier for me to understand it this way : 1) STATS is vector or single value that will be repeated to form a matrix of the same size as first input, 2) FUN will be applied on 1st input and this new matrix. Maybe better illustrated by : `sweep(matrix(1:6,nrow=2),2,7:9,list)` . It's usually more efficient than `apply`because where `apply` loops, `sweep` is able to use vectorised functions.

Answer (score 7):

In the *collapse* package recently released on CRAN, I have attempted to compress most of the common apply functionality into just 2 functions:

1. `dapply` (Data-Apply) applies functions to rows or (default) columns of matrices and data.frames and (default) returns an object of the same type and with the same attributes (unless the result of each computation is atomic and `drop = TRUE`). The performance is comparable to `lapply` for data.frame columns, and about 2x faster than `apply` for matrix rows or columns. Parallelism is available via `mclapply` (only for MAC).

Syntax:

```
dapply(X, FUN, ..., MARGIN = 2, parallel = FALSE, mc.cores = 1L, 
       return = c("same", "matrix", "data.frame"), drop = TRUE)
```

Examples:

```
# Apply to columns:
dapply(mtcars, log)
dapply(mtcars, sum)
dapply(mtcars, quantile)
# Apply to rows:
dapply(mtcars, sum, MARGIN = 1)
dapply(mtcars, quantile, MARGIN = 1)
# Return as matrix:
dapply(mtcars, quantile, return = "matrix")
dapply(mtcars, quantile, MARGIN = 1, return = "matrix")
# Same for matrices ...
```

2. `BY` is a S3 generic for split-apply-combine computing with vector, matrix and data.frame method. It is significantly faster than `tapply`, `by` and `aggregate` (an also faster than `plyr`, on large data `dplyr` is faster though).

Syntax:

```
BY(X, g, FUN, ..., use.g.names = TRUE, sort = TRUE,
   expand.wide = FALSE, parallel = FALSE, mc.cores = 1L,
   return = c("same", "matrix", "data.frame", "list"))
```

Examples:

```
# Vectors:
BY(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, sum)
BY(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, quantile)
BY(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, quantile, expand.wide = TRUE) # This returns a matrix 
# Data.frames
BY(iris[-5], iris$Species, sum)
BY(iris[-5], iris$Species, quantile)
BY(iris[-5], iris$Species, quantile, expand.wide = TRUE) # This returns a wider data.frame
BY(iris[-5], iris$Species, quantile, return = "matrix") # This returns a matrix
# Same for matrices ...
```

Lists of grouping variables can also be supplied to `g`.

Talking about performance: A main goal of *collapse* is to foster high-performance programming in R and to move beyond split-apply-combine alltogether. For this purpose the package has a full set of C++ based fast generic functions: `fmean`, `fmedian`, `fmode`, `fsum`, `fprod`, `fsd`, `fvar`, `fmin`, `fmax`, `ffirst`, `flast`, `fNobs`, `fNdistinct`, `fscale`, `fbetween`, `fwithin`, `fHDbetween`, `fHDwithin`, `flag`, `fdiff` and `fgrowth`. They perform grouped computations in a single pass through the data (i.e. no splitting and recombining).

Syntax:

```
fFUN(x, g = NULL, [w = NULL,] TRA = NULL, [na.rm = TRUE,] use.g.names = TRUE, drop = TRUE)
```

Examples:

```
v <- iris$Sepal.Length
f <- iris$Species

# Vectors
fmean(v)             # mean
fmean(v, f)          # grouped mean
fsd(v, f)            # grouped standard deviation
fsd(v, f, TRA = "/") # grouped scaling
fscale(v, f)         # grouped standardizing (scaling and centering)
fwithin(v, f)        # grouped demeaning

w <- abs(rnorm(nrow(iris)))
fmean(v, w = w)      # Weighted mean
fmean(v, f, w)       # Weighted grouped mean
fsd(v, f, w)         # Weighted grouped standard-deviation
fsd(v, f, w, "/")    # Weighted grouped scaling
fscale(v, f, w)      # Weighted grouped standardizing
fwithin(v, f, w)     # Weighted grouped demeaning

# Same using data.frames...
fmean(iris[-5], f)                # grouped mean
fscale(iris[-5], f)               # grouped standardizing
fwithin(iris[-5], f)              # grouped demeaning

# Same with matrices ...
```

In the package vignettes I provide benchmarks. Programming with the fast functions is significantly faster than programming with *dplyr* or *data.table*, especially on smaller data, but also on large data.

Answer (score 4):

Starting in R 4.3.0, `tapply` will support data frames and both `tapply` and `by` will support grouping data frame rows with a formula.

```r
> R.version.string
[1] "R version 4.3.0 beta (2023-04-07 r84200)"
> dd <- data.frame(x = 1:10, f = gl(5L, 2L), g = gl(2L, 5L))
    x f g
1   1 1 1
2   2 1 1
3   3 2 1
4   4 2 1
5   5 3 1
6   6 3 2
7   7 4 2
8   8 4 2
9   9 5 2
10 10 5 2
> tapply(dd, ~f + g, nrow)
   g
f   1 2
  1 2 0
  2 2 0
  3 1 1
  4 0 2
  5 0 2
> by(dd, ~g, identity)
g: 1
  x f g
1 1 1 1
2 2 1 1
3 3 2 1
4 4 2 1
5 5 3 1
------------------------------------------------------------ 
g: 2
    x f g
6   6 3 2
7   7 4 2
8   8 4 2
9   9 5 2
10 10 5 2
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some alternatives from some packages as well which are not discussed above.

The `parApply()` function in the `parallels` package provides an alternative to the apply family of functions for executing parallel computations on a cluster. Other alternatives for parallel computation in R include the `foreach` package and the `doParallel` package, which allow for parallel execution of loops and functions. The `future` package provides a simple and consistent API for using futures, which are a way to evaluate expressions asynchronously, either in parallel or sequentially. Additionally, the `purrr` package provides a functional programming approach to iteration and mapping, and supports parallelization through the `future` package.

Here are some examples

##### parApply() example:

```
library(parallel)

# Create a matrix
m <- matrix(1:20, nrow = 5)

# Define a function to apply to each column of the matrix
my_fun <- function(x) {
  x^2
}

# Apply the function to each column of the matrix in parallel
result <- parApply(cl = makeCluster(2), X = m, MARGIN = 2, FUN = my_fun)

# View the result
result
```

##### foreach example:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

# Register a parallel backend
registerDoParallel(cores = 2)

# Create a list of numbers
my_list <- list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

# Define a function to apply to each element of the list
my_fun <- function(x) {
  x^2
}

# Apply the function to each element of the list in parallel
result <- foreach(i = my_list) %dopar% my_fun(i)

# View the result
result
```

##### future example:

```
library(future)

# Plan to use a parallel backend
plan(multisession, workers = 2)

# Create a list of numbers
my_list <- list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

# Define a function to apply to each element of the list
my_fun <- function(x) {
  x^2
}

# Apply the function to each element of the list in parallel using futures
result <- future_map(my_list, my_fun)

# View the result
result
```

##### purrr example:

```
library(purrr)
library(future)

# Plan to use a parallel backend
plan(multisession, workers = 2)

# Create a list of numbers
my_list <- list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

# Define a function to apply to each element of the list
my_fun <- function(x) {
  x^2
}

# Apply the function to each element of the list in parallel using purrr
result <- future_map(my_list, my_fun)

# View the result
result
```

EDIT 2023-07-02 (by **future** author): Replaced deprecated and no-longer existing `multiprocess` **future** backend with `multisession`.

Comment: You want to create `cl <- makeCluster(2)` _once_ before calling `parLapply()`, and then use `stopCluster(cl)` at the end of the example to make sure they are shut down.  As it is written now, the example will spin up two new parallel workers _each_ time it is called, eventually clogging up the computer.