# Continue executing after browser()

Tags: debugging, r, browser

I'm debugging R code with [browser()](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/browser.html).
The function pauses the execution of the current R script and allows for inspection.
Is it possible to enable/disable the debug mode on the fly, during the execution?
With large scripts it would be very handy.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question prompted me to read `?browser`.  The documentation says you can use the `expr=` argument to `browser` to create (the illusion) of conditional debugging.  That, combined with a global option should give you what you want.

```
foo <- function(x) {
  browser(expr=isTRUE(getOption("myDebug")))
  mean(x)
}
foo(1:10)
options(myDebug=TRUE)
foo(1:10)  # invokes browser
```

Comment: +1 -- Thanks for reading `browser` for us all! I've always wrapped `browser` in `if` clauses for this purpose, but no longer.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien: you may still want to wrap it in `if` statements... `?browser` says that will be faster than using `expr=`.

Comment: OK, that's it...  Looks like I need to go read `?browser` once and for all!  Thanks.

Comment: Super nifty trick.  Added it to the debugging tricks compiled here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882734/what-is-your-favorite-r-debugging-trick/5156351#5156351