# min() error in function with while loop in R -a debugging challenge for the R enthusiast

Tags: r, debugging, while-loop, min

I have a function (bobB) that seems to be getting stuck in a while loop. When I hit escape and  look at warnings() I get the following error:

```
Warning message:
In min(xf, yf) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

Some example code:

```
#I have the data: 

x<-"A03" 
y<-"A24"

sitex<-c("Sp1","Sp1","Sp3","Sp3")
sitey<-c("Sp2","Sp4","Sp2","Sp4")
gsim<-c(0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1)
gsim<-data.frame(sitex,sitey,gsim)

site<-c("A03","A03","A03","A03","A24","A24","A24","A24")
species<-c("Sp1","Sp1","Sp3","Sp4","Sp1","Sp1","Sp3","Sp4")
freq<-c(0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1,0.3,0.3,0,0.4)
ssf<-data.frame(site,species,freq,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#My function:  

bobB <- function (x, y, ssf, gsim) {

#*Step 1.* Create an empty matrix 'specfreq' to fill 

#Selects the species frequency data greater than 0 for the two sites being compared  

ssfx <- ssf[ssf$site == x & ssf$freq >0,]
ssfy <- ssf[ssf$site == y & ssf$freq >0,]

#pull out the species that are present at site x and/or site y using a merge,  
#this is    needed to create the initial empty matrix  

m<-(merge(ssfx,ssfy,all=TRUE))
species<-unique(m$species)

#Creates an empty matrix of the frequency of each species at site x and y  

 specfreq <- matrix(0, length(species), 2, dimnames=list(species,c(x,y)))

#*Step 2.* Fill empty matrix 'specfreq' with data from data.frame 'ssf'  

for(i in 1:nrow(ssf{specfreq[rownames(specfreq)==ssf[i,"species"],colnames(specfreq)==ssf[i,"site"]] <- ssf[i,"freq"]}

#*Step 3.* For species present at site x and y remove the minimum of the two from both  
#find minimum frequency for each species for site x and y  

a <- pmin(specfreq[,x], specfreq[,y])

#subtract 'a' from current 'specfreq'  

specfreq <- specfreq - a

#*Step 4.* Calulate variable B  

#Set answer to 0

answer <- 0

#while 'specfreq' contains data (i.e. is >0) keep doing the following  

while(sum(specfreq) > 1e-10) {

#Find species remaining at site x  

sx <- species[specfreq[,1] > 0]

#Find species remaining at site y  

sy <- species[specfreq[,2] > 0]     

#Pull out the gsim value for sx and sy

gsimre <-gsim[gsim$sitex %in% sx & gsim$sitey %in% sy,]

#determines the row containing the maximum value for remaining gsim and assigns it to i     

i <- which.max(gsimre$gsim)

#once the max gsim value has been found (i) we go back to the specfreq matrix and filter  
#out the frequency of the site x species associated with i   

xf <- specfreq[(gsimre$sitex[i]),x]

#and the frequency of the site y species associated with i  

yf <- specfreq[(gsimre$sitey[i]),y]

#The frequency of the species at site x associated with the greatest i is multiplied by i           

answer <- answer + xf * gsimre$gsim[i]

#Then take the minimum common frequency for the two species associated with i  

f <- min(xf,yf)

#Subtract theminimum  common frequency from both the site x and site y column  

specfreq[gsimre$sitex[i],x] <- specfreq[gsimre$sitex[i],x]-f
specfreq[gsimre$sitey[i],y] <- specfreq[gsimre$sitey[i],y]-f   
}
answer
}
bobB(x, y, ssf, gsim)
```

Comment: Suggestions for debugging: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882734/what-is-your-favorite-r-debugging-trick/5156351#5156351

Comment: I *might* take a look at this if you make it much easier for me to copy and paste your code into a clean session. So, for starters, change your commentary to be either embedded code comments, or remove it (i.e. give me a single code block that works).

Comment: Why have you ignored the comments and answers from your previous post of this question?  It's obvious that `xf` and `yf` are empty, so you need to learn to debug. Work backwards to see what the values of `x,y,gsimre$sitex[i]` etc are until you find your error.

Comment: @Andrie Thanks. I have reformatted the question to be one chunk of code as suggested

Comment: @Carl Witthoft I have not ignored the comments made to my question about the min function. I was simply taking the advice of some of the comments and stating the problem in its entirety. It is still unclear to me what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here is your problem (I think):

```
xf <- specfreq[(gsimre$sitex[i]),x]
yf <- specfreq[(gsimre$sitey[i]),y]
```

`(gsimre$sitex[i])`and `(gsimre$sitey[i])`are factors which means that when you use them to index something there are interpreted as numeric and not as characters.
And indeed:

```
gsimre$sitey
[1] Sp4
Levels: Sp2 Sp4
```

Sp4, being the second factor, has a numerical value of 2, hence `specfreq[(gsimre$sitey[i]),y]` is `specfreq[2,2]` which is 0.

Hence, this should do the trick:

```
xf <- specfreq[as.character(gsimre$sitex[i]),x]
yf <- specfreq[as.character(gsimre$sitey[i]),y]
```

Or you declare them as being strings and not factors at the beginning, as you did for `ssf` but not for `gsim`:

```
gsim<-data.frame(sitex,sitey,gsim, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Because of this mistake `yf` was equal to 0 and therefore `f=min(xf,yf)`was always equal to 0, hence your endless loop.

P. S. : `answer` should be out of the `while` loop if you want the function to return it, i. e.

```
    }
answer
}
```

instead of

```
    answer
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks plannapus. That seems to have worked and I can now fun BobB. However, when I run the 'external function' which combined the functions bobA, bobB, and bobC I still get the error "In min(xf, yf) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf". I will post this as a different question though. Thanks again!